# how to reset the value of a AUTO_INCREMENT row in a mysql table

Tags: php, sql, auto-increment, reset

Lets say i have have a table with 200 records and i deleted all of them now when i try to add another record to that table i want the id of the record to start from 1 instead of 201.
i tried this code but doesn't work

```
$connection->query("ALTER TABLE table_name AUTO_INCREMENT = 1")
```

is there any other way to do this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to `truncate` the table:

```
TRUNCATE table `tablename`
```

> Logically, TRUNCATE TABLE is similar to a DELETE statement that deletes all rows, or a sequence of DROP TABLE and CREATE TABLE statements.
>
> Any AUTO_INCREMENT value is reset to its start value. This is true even for MyISAM and InnoDB, which normally do not reuse sequence values.

More information at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/truncate-table.html.

Comment: @surafel You're welcome! Please accept the answer by clicking on the tick mark below the upvote/ downvote buttons, thanks!